# VPS multiple sites help

Tags: vps, directory

I have a VPS which has a single website associated with a single IP,
This website is in wordpress and it is directly placed or installed into the `/html` directory, which means inside `/www/html/` my wordpress folders files, are placed, I mean to say its not in this form `/www/html/wordpress/wp-content` its in this form `/www/html/wp-content`

Now I am planning to have multiple sites with the same IP, in same VPS, 
But now I have to organize the folders for this,
But how can I?

If I transfer my current scattered website files into a particular folder like `www/html/site`, will be there any problem?

Or can I go ahead with the same situation, just placing a new folder into `/html` directory for my second website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive the short answer as I am on my phone...

How are you managing the server? Via control panel or via SSH?

Moving the wordpress files physical location is non-consequential as long as the db location and site url remain the same. http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

I sugguest you create a domain_tld folder within /www/html (ie. iainlbc_com), move the contents of /www/html there, then change the virtualhost to use /www/html/domain_tld as the root directory.

Comment: @ianinlbc but when I ll add my new website where will it go?
 /www/html/new_website or /www/html/domain_tld ???
Sorry for stupid question, this is my first time, and I am doing this through SSH

Comment: no problem ntechi - you can name it whatever you want, its arbitrary :) domain_tld is just the convention i use. for example my site iainlbc.com resides in /var/www/iainlbc_com. If you are using apache just change your DocumentRoot variable for the vhost.

Comment: ok then so finally I ll be having this kind of structure
for new website:`/var/www/html/new_site` and for old that is for current `/var/www/html/old_site`
In old_site and new_site folders my wordpress files will go, am I rite?

Comment: exactly! please report back here if you have problems